# Oracle update from multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

I want do the following in oracle:

```
update tableA tA 
set tA.value = (
  select tB.value 
  from tableB tB 
  inner join tableC tC 
  on tB.value = tC.value
)
```

It gives me ORA-01427. How i need to change the query to run it? If i add "and rownum=1" i can run the query but i will have the same result in all rows.

Comment: There is no key to join `tableA` and the resultset of your sub-query. Try to make it a correlated sub-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a relation between tableA and tableB/tableC that gives you exactly one row as a result.
Assumed, there is a relation between tableA and tableB on a column which is named "id".

```
update tableA tA 
set tA.value = (
  select tB.value 
  from tableB tB 
  inner join tableC tC 
  on tB.value = tC.value
  where tB.id = tA.id
)
```

Comment: Why do you mix `ANSI join syntax` and old `Oracle syntax`? Use any one syntax for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-01427

The issue with your **UPDATE** statement is that the sub-query is returning multiple rows, however, the **set clause** expects a single row. The only way you could make it work is to have a join candidate between the resultset of your sub-query and the table to be updated. Basically, you need to make it a **correlated sub-query**.

I would prefer using a **MERGE** statement as it is verbose and easy to interpret.

```
MERGE INTO tableA A 
USING (SELECT tB.value value,
  tB.join_candidate id
FROM tableB tB
INNER JOIN tableC tC
ON tB.VALUE = tC.VALUE
) b 
ON(b.ID = A.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET a.value = b.value;
```

Remember, you cannot update the column on which you are mentioning in the `ON` clause.

Comment: @thomas Good. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a minute to take the  tour to understand how this site works. http://stackoverflow.com/tour All the best!